# Implement qualify row_number

Tags: function, type-conversion, teradata, informatica

How to implement qualify row_number over(Partition by col order by col) and char2hexint() functions**(these are teradata functions)** in informatica in a way for which push down optimization(pdo) query is available?

Apart from sql overriding or using stored procedure ,is there any other solution?
Can rank transformation help here? ....But, I guess rank transformation cannot be pushed down..

help please !

Comment: Put the qualify and other functions in a view, and select from the view?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible.

Because either we need to use variable or Rank Transformation to achieve this. Both are not supported by PDO.

Answer (score 0):

To implement,  row_number over(Partition by col order by col) with PDO, please use aggregate transformation (use group by on columns in partition by ) and take max/min of columns in order by then self join.